# Passing c array in loadrunner

Tags: arrays, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

Is there any way to pass c array variable, one by one in a request body?
I have a correlated variable, let's say tokenID, which I'll save into a c array variable each time the request is called.The number of times the request is called varies and hence does the number of elements in the array.Now I would like to pass them one by one into a single request body.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.   The C compiler in LoadRunner is a derivative of LCC.  It is an ANSI compliant C compiler.   So, as you can pass any other data structure in C by reference, you should be able to do that in LoadRunner as well.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCC_(compiler)